# Joining two tables on oracle, where one column on table A is looking for values on two columns on Table B

Tags: oracle

I am trying to join two tables, Table A have one column "Col1" with Account no and ID values, and Table B have two columns Name Account "Dev" and ID column "Ops", I am trying to join table B to table A in a condition that Col1 = dev column on table B, or Col1 v= Ops column on table B

select * from Table a, Table b
where a.Col1 = b.Dev
or a.Col1 = b.Ops

Comment: Hey @Yamkela, the question is not clear. Did you face an error while performing this?
Also, could you specify the column names and their significance more clearly?

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number. This is an error I am getting, @NathanHughes.

Comment: @NathanHughes. I want to join two tables, Table A have one column with ID' and Account No's, and Table B have two columns, one for Account and ID Column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about datatype mismatch. As you didn't post your tables' description, I'll show it on Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables.

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)  --> I'll join it to DEPT.DEPTNO
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)  --> I'll join it to DEPT.LOC
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)

SQL> desc dept
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(14)
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(13)
```

---

This is how your current query looks like:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp e, dept d
  3  where e.ename = d.deptno
  4     or e.sal = d.loc;
where e.ename = d.deptno
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

See? Exactly the same error as you got, because `ENAME`'s datatype is `VARCHAR2`, while `DEPTNO` is a `NUMBER`. So let's convert number to a string:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp e, dept d
  3  where e.ename = to_char(d.deptno)
  4     or e.sal   = d.loc;
   or e.sal   = d.loc
                *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Ah, still the same error, but now asterisk points to a different column. Why? Because `SAL` is a `NUMBER`, while `LOC` is a `VARCHAR2`. So, convert SAL to a string:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp e, dept d
  3  where e.ename        = to_char(d.deptno)
  4     or to_char(e.sal) = d.loc;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Right, now it works. Though, no rows are returned as there are no matches, but - there's no error either.

---

Side note: you'd rather properly `JOIN` tables; leave `WHERE` clause for *conditions* data should meet.

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp e join dept d on e.ename        = to_char(d.deptno)
  3                        and to_char(e.sal) = d.loc;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error message - which you disclosed in a comment instead of including it in your original question (as you should have done).

It indicates that the `Ops` (ID) column in the second table is `number` data type. When the query attempts to match a name like `'Joe'` from the `Col1` column in the first table against a number like `2381` (an id) - as it will do when `'Joe'` does not match the name column in the second table - it will attempt to convert the string `'Joe'` to a number, resulting in the error you saw. In a case like that, Oracle attempts to convert the string to a number, not the other way around.

The workaround is simple - compare `a.Col1` to `to_char(b.Ops)`.

Hopefully you will be able to fix the first table - its design is fatally flawed. You shouldn't have to put up with such nonsense in the first place.